# Встречено else, а ожидался оператор. В чем проблема?

Tags: pascal

```
var a,b,c: integer;
  begin
    Write('Ведите день недели:');
read (a);
  if ((a>=1) and (a<=5)) then
    write ('Ведите время:');
   else
     if ((a<1) or (a>5)) then
    write ('Ведите время:');
read (b);
  if (b<=18) then 
    write ('Время пришло')
   else
     if ((a<1) or (a>5)) or (b<18) then
     write ('Время не пришло')
  end.
```

Задача
Введите номер дня недели и время в часах и определите, пришло ли время занятия.
Занятия проходят по рабочим дням после 18 (18 включительно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед `else` точка с запятой не ставится.